# jQuery/Javascript keypress validation function or plugin - don't fire on certain keys - crossbrowser

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, keypress

I'm looking for some code that would validate whether or not the key pressed is a key that changes the value of the textarea.

It should be cross browser, (Mac and Windows), and not fire when keys like Command, alt/option, control, fn, volume, etc. I'm hoping there is a good plugin for this, or someone would be willing to put the time in making a quick function or whatever for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about a plugin but you can use jQuery's .keypress() and then include/exclude certain keys.

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Something like this perhaps:

```
$("#elem").keypress(function(event) {
    if ( event.which >= 65 && event.which <= 90 ) {
        // Do something with A - Z characters...
    }
}
```

---

In response to you multi-key comment...

There are additional properties on the event object that you can use:

```
if(event.which == 65 && event.ctrlKey)...

event.ctrlKey    
event.shiftKey
event.metaKey
event.altKey
```

Comment: does this do 0-9?, a-z and 0-9 are the most important keys, (this is for telling a user when a user is typing in the chat)

Comment: @DylanCross My example just happened to use A-Z but yes you could expand it to accept any number of chars. Or you can use it to instead exclude certain chars from the event like a carriage return (13). See an ASCII table for decimal values (assuming you're only concerned with ASCII): http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Yeah, thanks that seems to work well for what I want it for, so thanks

Comment: Do you know if there's an easy way to know when the user is pressing multiple keys at a time, so like. if a user does Alt + R or something like that, so it doesn't count that as a keypress.

Comment: @DylanCross Added additional info to the post on multi-key.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I had done before, however it doesn't work when the specified key is pressed alone, IE. if I set it to R && alt, R doesn't work all the time, as it should. But not work when alt is also pressed. This would work for this particular thing im working on now, however there are times when this wouldn't work.